# Functional Analysis Norms

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume 1 <= p < q <= ∞. Explain why the norm ||.||q  is a well-defined norm on lp
and prove that the norms|| · ||p and || ·||q on lp are not equivalent when p = 1 and q = ∞.

Can you help me with this as I am not sure on how to start? Should I find a sequence that is convergent for one norm and not for the other?

Comment: If the series $\sum_n |a_n|^p$ converges, then almost all terms $|a_n|$ are in $[0,1/2)$. Therefore, if $q>p$, then for all those terms $|a_n|^q\leq |a_n|^p$. This implies that the series $\sum_n|a_n|^q$ will also converge.

Answer (score 0):

The fa ct that $\|x\|_q <\infty$ for all R$x \in l^{p}$ follows from the fact that $x_n \to )$ so $|x_n|^{q} \leq |x_n|^{p}$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

To show that $\|x\|_1$ and $\|x\|_{\infty}$ are not equivalent note that $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n}\frac {e_k} k \to 0$ in the second norm but not in the first norm.

Here $(e_k)$ is the usual basis. $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n} \frac  1 k\geq \sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n} \frac  1 {2n}>\frac 1 2$ for  all $n$.